# what jboss ports do we need to open in a firewall?

Tags: jboss, port, firewall, jboss7.x

We have an application that runs on Jboss 7 and when we install it on the client site we would like to tell him which ports to open in the firewall, we are not sure which one are absolutely necessary:

- EJB3 Remoting Connector  (we are using MDB)
- JNDI
- IIOP (RMI)
- JMX RMI (We are not using JMX)
- SMNP (Not using it)
- JMS (we have some inner queues accessed locally)
- clustering (we are not using clustering so i guess we don't need that one)
- Remoting
- Messaging

Comment: Depends on which of those you use.

Comment: Start with HTTP on port 80 and 8080, and see how you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Security_on_JBoss-Configuring_JBoss_for_use_Behind_a_Firewall.html)  is a good starting point. My suggestion would be to try the setup locally, figure out the correct ports and then pass it on to the client. Troubleshooting this setup at the client site is really not a good idea.

Update [Another link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJBossBehindAFirewall?_sscc=t) : A little more detailed.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Let me assure you we have no intention of testing it at the client site, its just that currently we demanding all the ports to be open and we want to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

In more recent versions of the application server (WildFly), the only application port exposed by default is port 8080 and 8443 if https is enabled.
On a Linux machine, you would typically use:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port 8080/tcp  --permanent
```

Source: [How to run JBoss through a firewall](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/how-to-run-wildfly-and-jboss-eap-through-a-firewall)